# Is there a way to create the same dropdownlist over multiple excel sheets, selectable from any sheet, affecting all the other

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, excel-formula

Is there a way to create Drop down lists in multiple sheets referencing the same list (doesn't matter where it is stored). Once the user has selected something from Sheet 1 drop down, when he browse in Sheet 2, he should be able to see the same selection and can also change the selection in Sheet 2 - affecting the selection in Sheet 1. It's like the logic in the drop down lists in web pages where we browses different pages yet our selection remains and also you are given the chance to change your selection wherever page you are.

The list ist easy. The user chooses between "weak" and "strong". This should be chooseable from all sheets, affecting all the other dropdownlists with the same selction.

Comment: You could do this with VBA, using the `Workbook_SheetChange` event to apply any changes to the other sheets in the workbook.

Comment: Is there an other formular approach beside VB? oneDrive doesnt allow makros on excel online.

Comment: You can't have multiple cells all referencing each other just using formulas.  You might be able to use Office js if you're familiar with that.